# CodeSpaces missing scrolling in forums

Tags: svn, project-hosting

Does anyone uses CodeSpaces.com for project integration?

If so, dows the scrolling on the forums works for you?

I have contacted CodeSpaces support but still have no answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to resolve this will be applied this weekend.

F